# The pictures I sent were horrible or the pictures I sent are horrible? Which one is correct and why?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, time

> The pictures I sent were horrible

or

> The pictures I sent are horrible

Which is correct and why? If I use "were "does it mean that in the present time the pictures are no longer horrible?

Answer (score 4):

Both of them are grammatically correct, but I find the version with **were** to be more natural, because then the tenses of *sent* and *were* match.  It's true that the pictures might still be horrible, but usually, the important thing (I think) is that they *were* horrible *when you sent them*.

I can think of cases in which I would use either version:

> In 1980 I entered a photo contest.  I did not win, of course.  The pictures I sent were horrible.

In this case I would definitely use *were*, because the important thing is that they were horrible when you sent them, even if they still exist and are just as horrible.

> "I sent the client photos this morning, but he's really unhappy and just yelled at me on the phone." 
> "Why, what's wrong?"
> "The pictures that I sent are horrible."

In this case, *are* works too, because we're talking about the current state of the photos and the client's current opinion, even though the sending is in the past.

Comment: Ok now i understand. This sentence that I asked in the post was sent to my friend about our pictures in the yearbook. Based on what you said I therefore got the answer for my situation. I would use are because at that time when we talked our yearbook just came out. So, I would consider it to be a recent event. Thank you for your answer anyways! It makes me understand more in other contexts as well!

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. Nothing has changed about the pictures now if you use the past tense to talk about what they were when you sent them.

There's very little difference to my ear. If you are talking to a friend about pictures you sent recently and you are worried about how they will be viewed, perhaps "are horrible" is better. If you are talking about something that happened a while ago, say "were horrible".

Comment: Ok but here the things, I keep thinking everytimes I speak/write english what if the action that happened in the past is still true so it makes me confusing which tense to use present or past. I was told once to remember it this way “if the events or actions already happened just use past tense regardless if it’s still true” however Im not sure how much I can believe in this statement

Comment: The past tense states something about the past; it entails nothing about the present. Now in cases where change is impossible, then past tense necessarily entails present as well. In cases where change is possible, the past entails nothing unless you **choose** to clarify. “I loved her once” implies that love has died. “I loved her then and still do” explicitly states that love has persisted.